# How to create a layer from existing attribute data of another layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, layers

I am using Arc Map 10.2 and I have a shapefile consisting of parcel data.  I would like to create a shapefile/layer from the existing parcel shapefile by using a table that consists of a list of addresses that match up to the attribute associated with the parcel layer.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Do you just want to join attributes from the table to the shapefile? A you trying to create a new shapefile based on a selection/subset of parcels? What is the relationship between the shapefile attributes and the list of addresses - do the parcels have an address attribute or some other common attribute? Does the list of addresses represent parcels that all share a common attribute within the shapefile, but you don't have a common attribute like the address between the list and shapefile to join on?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all you need is a simple join. Use the join tool and use a common field to combine the table and shapefile together.

[ESRI Help: About Joining and Relating Tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/)

**EDIT:** I see now it is a new shapefile you want. In that case I would still do the join and then save the joined shapefile as a new shapefile.

Comment: Assuming this is what asker is trying to do, you could also use the [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool to eliminate the step of exporting/saving the result to a new file.